# Databinding Dropdownlist with data table and adding custom value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am databinding my dropdownlist with a datatable.And I need to add one more item to the dropdown list which needs to be the first item in selection..I had tried many ways but nothing working.

```
ddlCountry.Items.Add("--Select--");
ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Country";
ddlCountry.DataValueField = "Country";
ddlCountry.DataSource = dt;
ddlCountry.DataBind();
```

Comment: Have you tried to bind the source to a list of items, add the extra one, and then bind the dropdown using this list as the source?

Comment: The answer given by @hallie is a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your page declaration:

```
<asp:dropdownlist id="ddlCountry" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" >
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="[ Select ]" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:dropdownlist>

AppendDataBoundItems="true" is the key.
```

Your code behind:

```
ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Country";
ddlCountry.DataValueField = "Country";
ddlCountry.DataSource = dt;
ddlCountry.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Country";
 ddlCountry.DataValueField = "Country";
 ddlCountry.DataSource = dt;
 ddlCountry.DataBind();
 ddlCountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Country", "0"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Data bind first before you add

```
ddlCountry.DataTextField = "Country";
ddlCountry.DataValueField = "Country";
ddlCountry.DataSource = dt;
ddlCountry.DataBind();
ddlCountry.Items.Add("--Select--");
```