# Databind drop down list with "Please Select" not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I am trying to add "please select" item to my drop down list after adding databind but it doesn't seem to work. This is what I am trying,

```
ddlListMine.Items.Add(new ListItem("Please Please Please Select....", "-1"));
ddlListMine.DataSource = GetSomeChickens();
ddListMine.DataTextField = "ChickenName";
ddListMine.DataValueField= "NumberOfEggsChickenLay";
ddListMine.DataBind();
```

I also tried moving First line of code to last, but then "Please please..." item comes in end of drop down list.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783756/databinding-dropdownlist-with-data-table-and-adding-custom-value

Comment: @HABJAN I can't use ASP.NET to add "Please select" item , as mentioned in the answer of question you added link to

Comment: hm.. the tag says "asp.net". Anyways, just add ddlListMine.AppendDataBoundItems = true to your code and you are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert your item at Oth Index

```
    ddlListMine.DataSource = GetSomeChickens();
    ddListMine.DataTextField = "ChickenName";
    ddListMine.DataValueField= "NumberOfEggsChickenLay";
    ddListMine.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Please Please Select....", "0"));
    ddListMine.DataBind();
```

Comment: Have you tested this? it is not working. If you want to insert an extra listitem always add it after binding the ddl.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first bind your datalist then set an empty value listitem to selected.

```
ddlListMine.DataSource = GetSomeChickens();
ddListMine.DataTextField = "ChickenName";
ddListMine.DataValueField= "NumberOfEggsChickenLay";
ddListMine.DataBind();
ddlListMine.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Category", String.Empty));
ddListMine.SelectedIndex = 0;
```